# Orgmode exports second-level headings as enumerate

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm exporting a simple document from orgmode to latex, but the second-level headings are exported as items in a enumerate environment instead of as subsections.

This is the org file:

```
#+TITLE: Latex question
#+AUTHOR: J. Dow
#+OPTIONS: H:3

* This shows up as a sections
Loren
** But this ends up in enumerate
Loren 2
```

The resulting latex file is:

```
% Created 2020-04-03 vie. 16:54
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{J. Dow}
\date{\today}
\title{Latex question}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={J. Dow},
 pdftitle={Latex question},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\section{This shows up as a sections}
\label{sec:org4f3686e}
Loren
\begin{enumerate}
\item But this ends up in enumerate
\label{sec:org6fef945}
Loren 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Things I've tried:

- Using the `#+OPTIONS: H:3` line with multiple values and doing a `C-c C-c` as recommended in many places. No matter what the value of `H`, the value of `org-export-headline-levels` is always 3

I'm using emacs 26.1 and orgmode 9.1.9 in windows 10.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the value of `org-latex-classes`? You can get that with  `C-h v org-latex-classes RET`.  FWIW, when I process your file above with `H:3`, I get a section and a subsection.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. The default class is an article. However, I already solved the issue. Turns out I had a wrongly defined `org-latex-classes` variable that was the source of the problem. No idea how I broke it, but its fixed now